# Pulling data from an API using Axios on react.js. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm attempting to pull data from the array below. My code is below my console.log. What am I doing wrong? Nothing is rendering when I attempt to pull the data.

```
(356) […]
​
[0…99]
0: Object { TournamentID: 405, Name: "The Presidents Cup", StartDate: "2021-09-30T00:00:00", … }​​
1: Object { TournamentID: 453, Name: "Tour Championship", StartDate: "2021-09-02T00:00:00", … }​​
2: Object { TournamentID: 452, Name: "BMW Championship", StartDate: "2021-08-26T00:00:00", … }
​​
```

Below is the code I'm using to pull the data.

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(()=>{
    axios
    .get('https://api.sportsdata.io/golf/v2/json/Tournaments?key=72259e02756442d38c6b837dd8625e4f')
    .then((res)=> {
      
     console.log(res.data)
     setData(res.data)
})

  },[])

  return (
    
    <div className="App">
        
        <div className='container'>
        
        <h1>{data.Name}</h1>
        

      </div>
      
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You are using data is an object, but it seems to be an array, you should use map to iterate over the elements. In this case data.Name is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to map over the array of data with something like this:

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    <div className='container'>
      {data.map(item => <h1 key={item.TournamentID}>{item.Name}</h1>)}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

You also need the key attribute.

Comment: Single letter variables is not the best approach, even here. Better change it to `item => ` or something.

Comment: I agree. I'll update the answer. This stems from the use of generic terms such as `data` - if this was my code, I'd suggest changing `data` to `items` (plural indicates an array or collection) and the `d` would become `item`.